# Upper bound of sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to find a suitable upper bound for the following expression, i. e. find constants $C_1, C_2\ge 0$ such that
$x\sin(y)\le C_1 |x|^2+ C_2 |y|^2$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R^n}$.
Initially, I thought I would be done by Young's inequality but then I end up with $\frac12 |x|^2+\frac{\sin^2(y)}{2}.$ From here, $C_1$ is easy to define but what about $C_2$?

Answer (score 2):

$\sin (y)$ does not make sense for $y \in \mathbb R^{n}$ so I will assume that $n=1$.

$|x\sin(y)| \leq |xy| \leq \frac 1 2(x^{2}+y^{2})$.

Answer (score 0):

Since$$\sin^2(y)\leqslant y^2,$$you can take $C_2=\frac12$.